# How can I do SQL JOIN by bitwise operator manipulation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bit-manipulation, sql-server-2014

We have a `SQL Server 2014` database containing two tables:

[image]

[image]

In the Parts table BitColours is a bitwise number referencing rows from the Colours table.

we have been asked to produce a query like this:

[image]

I've never done this type of manipulation before so would appreciate any guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to connected two tables by `AND` bitwise operator(`&`).

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.part,
     STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + c.Colour
          FROM colours c
          WHERE c.BitId & p.BitColurs > 0
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') colours
FROM parts p
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2f4d6/2/0)**:

```
| id |   part |     colours |
|----|--------|-------------|
|  1 | abc123 |    Red,Blue |
|  2 | xyt788 | Black,Green |
```

**Explain**

`&` AND bitwise operator will compare two binary from two value.

for example :

`BitColor` is `3` = `00011`.

here is a sample I ignore many zero after binary 16.

**Red**

```
    00011
---------------------
(&) 00001 = Red (1)
---------------------
    00001 = (1)
```

**Blue**

```
    00011
---------------------
(&) 00010 = Blue (2)
---------------------
    00010 = (2)
```

**Black**

```
    00011
---------------------
(&) 00100 = Black (4)
---------------------
    00000 = (0)
```

**Green**

```
    00011
---------------------
(&) 01000 = Green (8)
---------------------
    00000 = (0)
```

---

So we can use  `BitId` & `BitColurs` do calculation by binary, and get the result which greater `0` mean You can get the value.

Comment: Of course, a better solution would be to normalize the database and add a partsToColors table, but your answer is good in case that's impossible.

Comment: it a bit more complicated than that with the real data... I have over simplified it to ask the question

Comment: Could you explain what `STUFF` and ``XML PATH` are doing here?